# Drawing marching ants using directx

Tags: image-processing, graphics, directx

I have to draw a selection feedback like Photoshop in my directx application. I came across an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_ants) on wikipedia to do this. But, I am not sure if its the right way to do this especially if my selection area could be any arbitrary geometry. Has someone implemented it using Directx? Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: You could just calculate the pattern in the pixel shader and draw the border as a line strip. Just pass an offset parameter `t` to the shader and use the screen coordinates of the pixel. `t` will increment every now and then to animate the border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment here is a simple pixel shader to achieve the wanted result:

```
float4 PS( float4 pos : SV_POSITION) : SV_Target
{
    float w = ((int)(pos.x + pos.y + t) % 8);
    return (w < 4 ? float4(0,0,0,1) : float4(1,1,1,1));
}
```

`x` and `y` are added to produce the diagonal stripe pattern. You can imagine it as follows: If `y` is constant and `x` increases by 1, `w` also increases by 1. The same applies for `y`. So for `w` to stay constant, you have to go `(x+1, y-1)` or `(x-1, y+1)` (or other step sizes). We use the `%` operator to produce a periodicity of 8 pixels. The first half period is filled black and the second half white.

This is an equivalent, but more performant shader. It uses bit operations instead of modulo and comparisons.

```
float4 PS( float4 pos : SV_POSITION) : SV_Target
{
    int w = ((int)(pos.x + pos.y + t) & 4);
    return float4(w,w,w,1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do it for a bitmap mask (not just for rects and beziers)? Could you please explain a bit.

Comment: Just find the mask's contour and draw it as a line strip using the above pixel shader. Or did you mean something different?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about this shader? Why are you adding x and y together and then doing AND with 4?